# Data allocation error in the CreateSalesPrice method

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

**Situation:**

I have to asign price per subitem on both the Vendor Price Worksheets screen and Vendor Prices screen.

When the release button is pressed in Vendor Price Worksheets, the records in the APPriceWorksheetDetail table have to be created in the APVendorPrice table, Obviously I have to assign the SubItemID field value of the APPriceWorksheetDetail table to the UsrSubItemID field of the APVendorPrice table.

**Notes:**

It was not necessary to create the SubItemID field in Vendor Price Worksheets grid because it already existed in Details dataview.

I created the SubItemID field in Vendor Prices grid because it didn't exist in Records dataview.

**This is my Vendor Price Worksheets screen**

[image]

**This is my Vendor Prices screen**

[image]

**This is my APVendorPriceExtensions DAC**

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APVendorPriceExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APVendorPrice>
  {
    #region UsrSubItemID
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.defaultSubItemID,
    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APVendorPrice.inventoryID>>,
    And<InventoryItem.defaultSubItemOnEntry, Equal<boolTrue>>>>),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Default<APVendorPrice.inventoryID>))]
    [SubItem(typeof(APVendorPrice.inventoryID))]
    public virtual int? UsrSubItemID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrSubItemID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrSubItemID> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

I found the method that assigns the values in APPriceWorkSheetMain graph, the method is called CreateSalesPrice, I'm trying to override that method putting my custom UsrSubItemID field but I get the following error: "CS0117: 'APVendorPrice' does not contain a definition for 'UsrSubItemID'".

**This is my APPriceWorkSheetMain_Extension**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Api;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AP;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APPriceWorksheetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPriceWorksheetMaint>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate APVendorPrice CreateSalesPriceDelegate(APPriceWorksheetDetail priceLine, Nullable<Boolean> isPromotional, Nullable<DateTime> effectiveDate, Nullable<DateTime> expirationDate);
    [PXOverride]
    public APVendorPrice CreateSalesPrice(APPriceWorksheetDetail priceLine, Nullable<Boolean> isPromotional, Nullable<DateTime> effectiveDate, Nullable<DateTime> expirationDate, CreateSalesPriceDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      APVendorPrice newSalesPrice = new APVendorPrice
        {
            VendorID = priceLine.VendorID,
            InventoryID = priceLine.InventoryID,
            UsrSubItemID = priceLine.SubItemID,
            SiteID = priceLine.SiteID,
            UOM = priceLine.UOM,
            BreakQty = priceLine.BreakQty,
            SalesPrice = priceLine.PendingPrice,
            CuryID = priceLine.CuryID,
            IsPromotionalPrice = isPromotional,
            EffectiveDate = effectiveDate,
            ExpirationDate = expirationDate,
        };

        return newSalesPrice;
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Any advice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the following approach? (updating through the extension DAC):

```
  APVendorPrice newSalesPrice = new APVendorPrice
        {
            VendorID = priceLine.VendorID,
            InventoryID = priceLine.InventoryID,            
            SiteID = priceLine.SiteID,
            UOM = priceLine.UOM,
            BreakQty = priceLine.BreakQty,
            SalesPrice = priceLine.PendingPrice,
            CuryID = priceLine.CuryID,
            IsPromotionalPrice = isPromotional,
            EffectiveDate = effectiveDate,
            ExpirationDate = expirationDate,
        };

        var vendorPriceExt = PXCache<APVendorPrice>.GetExtension<APVendorPriceExt>(newSalesPrice);
        vendorPriceExt.UsrSubItemID = priceLine.SubItemID;

        return newSalesPrice;
```

Comment: I just added those two code lines and it works perfectly!! Thanks for sharing that information @JosephCaruana